# Calling SuppressFinalize multiple times

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, suppressfinalize

Is there any downside of calling `GC.SuppressFinalize(object)` multiple times?
Protected `Dispose(bool)` method of *the dispose pattern* checks whether it is called before but there is no such check in the public `Dispose()` method.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_Disposed)
        return;

    if (disposing)
    {
        // Cleanup managed resources.
    }

    // Cleanup unmanaged resources.
    _Disposed = true;
}

~MyClass() { Dispose(false); }
```

Is it ok to call the `Dispose()` method of a `MyClass` instance multiple times?

Comment: Don't bother GC unless you don't have another choice.

Comment: I want to make one thing clear: You only need a finalizer if you need to dispose of unmanaged resources (or if you run whacky caching schemes relying on finalization).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx, it sets some bit in object header, so there shouldn't be any implications of calling it multiple times.

Comment: "If obj does not have a finalizer or the GC has already signaled the finalizer thread to run the finalizer, the call to the SuppressFinalize method has no effect."