# Is it safe to use a session-owned SQL Server sp_getapplock with EF6 DbContexts?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am wondering about the risks/safety of using an EF context with `sp_getapplock` and the session owner type. Based on the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx), my understanding is that a session owner means the lock will be released when the session ends if not explicitly release before that. I am assuming this also means the connection ends.

I have all this working already with transaction-owned locks, but that brings with it other issues and complications, so I am wondering about doing it with session-owned locks and how that will or won't collide with the behavior of `DbContext` and its connection handling.

I am not 100% sure how `DbContext` works by default, whether it uses a pool or each context instance opens and closes its own connections (the docs I've read seem to suggest the latter). For this question assume I'm not doing anything with connection management (I rarely do), so EF is handling that, or whatever handles it is handling it.

If I create a `DbContext` instance, grab the connection, execute SQL to create a *session-owned* lock, use the context as normal, *don't* release the lock and dispose of the context, will this work correctly? (In reality, this would be in an `IDisposable` wrapper to prevent that, but the question remains.)

To illustrate poorly:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext()) {
    var conn = ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
    conn.ExecuteSqlSomehow("sp_getapplock blahblah");
    try {
        // Lots of queries, savechanges, etc.
    } finally {
        // Oops I forgot to conn.ExecuteSql("sp_release the lock");
    }
}

await WatchMovieAsync();

using (var ctx = new MyContext()) {
    // Can this reuse the same connection, session and/or lock?
}
```

Questions:

1. Could another context somehow re-use my connection and its session lock after I dispose of the instance?
2. For that matter, could another context (e.g. in another thread) use a connection on which I issued the lock while the original thread is still within the `using` block?
3. Could EF close the locked connection and open another one later within the same `using` block (e.g. for `SaveChanges`), thereby releasing the lock?

Answer (score 9):

The answer appears to be no.  Apparently, the main issue is that there are calls to sp_reset_connection whenever a pooled connection is re-used from the pool (not when released back to the pool) which should release any session based locks.  [This social.msdn link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/84223e92-a41e-4681-a431-7f1b40a634a5/locking-in-entityframework-calling-empty-stored-procedure-releases-lock-acquired-using?forum=transactsql) claims that sp_reset_connection is even called between EF commands.

The simplest solution is to use a dedicated connection that stays open for the duration of the lock and not use it for other SQL if the API might interleave any sp_resest_connection calls (profiling could prove this).

Also see [SqlConnection vs Sql Session. Do their lifetimes coincide?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16613242/538763)

and [what-does-exec-sp-reset-connection-mean-in-sql-server-profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120)

Here is a C# sp_GetAppLock() wrapper we are trying (disclaimer--not thoroughly tested):

Usage:

```
using (new globalApplicationSqlServerLock(connectionString, "theUniqueLockName")
{
   // protected code
}
```

Implmentation:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CompanyNamespace.Server.DataAdaptersCommon
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A wrapper around sp_GetAppLock (SQL Server), useful for global locking (by arbitrary name) across multiple machines.
    /// For instance:  Include the compatibility version number within the lock resource to create a version specific lock.
    /// </summary>
    public class GlobalApplicationSqlServerLock : SimplifiedDisposableBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Last returned value from sp_GetAppLock() or sp_ReleaseAppLock()
        /// </summary>
        public Int32 LastReturnCode { get; private set; }

         /// <summary>
        /// The SQL Connection to use.
        /// </summary>
        readonly SqlConnection _connection;

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the lock chosen by the callse
        /// </summary>
        readonly string _lockName;
        
        /// <summary>
        /// The cumulative times that Lock() has been called.
        /// </summary>
        int _lockCount;

        // Refer to sp_GetAppLock()
        //
        const string _lockOwner = "session";
        const string _lockMode = "Exclusive";
        const string _dbPrincipal = "public";

        /// <summary>
        /// Wait a maximum of this many seconds.
        /// </summary>
        Int32 _waitForLockMaxSeconds;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor accepting a Connection String
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString">Connection string should include "...;AppName=AppType,WebPid" to improve DB side logging.</param>
        /// <param name="lockName"></param>
        /// <param name="waitForLockMaxSeconds">Throw an exception if the lock cannot be acquired within this time period.</param>
        /// <param name="lockNow">True to obtain the lock via the contructor call.  Lock is always released in Dipose()</param>
        /// <param name="excludeFromOpenTransactionScope">True to exclude from any open TransactionScope</param>
        public GlobalApplicationSqlServerLock(
            string connectionString, 
            string lockName,
            Int32 waitForLockMaxSeconds = 30, 
            bool lockNow = true,
            bool excludeFromOpenTransactionScope = true)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder conStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

            if (excludeFromOpenTransactionScope)
                conStrBuilder.Enlist = false;

            _waitForLockMaxSeconds = waitForLockMaxSeconds;

            // The lock must use a dedicated connection that stays open for the duration of the lock.
            // Otherwise, since the lock owner is "session", when the connection is closed the lock "may" be 
            // released since connection pooling could have inconsistent side effects.  So caller must ensure
            // lock is released (using IDisposable, etc).
            //
            _connection = new SqlConnection(conStrBuilder.ConnectionString);           
            _connection.Open();
            _lockName = lockName;

            if (lockNow)
                Lock();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Lock
        /// </summary>
        public void Lock()
        {
            string errMsg;
            if (!TryLock(out errMsg))
                throw new Exception(errMsg);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Try lock
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="errMsg"></param>
        /// <returns>True if lock obtained, false if not with error message.</returns>
        public bool TryLock(out string errMsg)
        {                    
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = _connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.CommandText = "sp_GetAppLock"; 
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Resource", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255) { Value = _lockName });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockMode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32) { Value = _lockMode });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockOwner", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32) { Value = _lockOwner });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockTimeout", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = _waitForLockMaxSeconds * 1000 });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DBPrincipal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128) { Value = _dbPrincipal }); 
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue });
 
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 
                LastReturnCode =  (int)command.Parameters["@Result"].Value;
            }
 
            switch (LastReturnCode)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    _lockCount++;
                    errMsg = null;
                    return true;
                case -1:
                    errMsg = "The lock request timed out.";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    errMsg = "The lock request was canceled.";
                    break;
                case -3:
                    errMsg = "The lock request was chosen as a deadlock victim.";
                    break;
                case -999:
                    errMsg = "Indicates a parameter validation or other call error.";
                    break;
                default:
                    errMsg = "Unexpected return value";
                    break;
            }

            return false;            
        }
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Release the lock
        /// </summary>
        public void Release()
        {
            string errMsg;
 
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = _connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.CommandText = "sp_ReleaseAppLock";
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Resource", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255) { Value = _lockName }); 
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LockOwner", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32) { Value = _lockOwner });
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DBPrincipal", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128) { Value = _dbPrincipal }); 
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue });
 
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                LastReturnCode = (int)command.Parameters["@Result"].Value;
            }
 
            switch (LastReturnCode)
            {
                case 0:
                    _lockCount--;
                    return;
                case -999:
                    errMsg = "Indicates a parameter validation or other call error.";
                    break;
                default:
                    errMsg = "Unexpected return value";
                    break;
            }
 
            throw new Exception(errMsg); 
        }
 
        /// <summary>
        /// Disposable implmentation
        /// </summary>
        protected override void FreeManagedResources()
        {            
            try
            {
                while (_lockCount > 0)
                    Release();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_connection != null && _connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                        _connection.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    base.FreeManagedResources();
                }
            }             
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CompanyNamespace.Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// To support IDisposable, pass true to constructor and call:
    /// 
    ///         AutoDispose(IDisposable) for each disposable at time of creation,
    ///         
    /// Or override these as needed:
    /// 
    ///         FreeManagedResources() and 
    ///         FreeUnmanagedResources()
    ///         
    /// Multi-thread safe.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class SimplifiedDisposableBase : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Flag for IDisposable
        /// </summary>
        protected bool _isDisposed = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// List of items that should be Dispose() when the instance is Disposed()
        /// </summary>
        private List<IDisposable> _autoDisposables = new List<IDisposable>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public SimplifiedDisposableBase()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finalizer (needed for freeing unmanaged resources and adds a check a Dispose() check for managed resources).
        /// </summary>
        ~SimplifiedDisposableBase()
        {
            // Warning:  An exception here will end the application.
            // Do not attempt to lock to a possibly finalized object within finalizer
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163603/why-garbage-collector-takes-objects-in-the-wrong-order            

            string errMessages = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                errMessages = String.Format("Warning:  Finalizer was called on class '{0}' (base class '{1}').  " +
                    "IDisposable's should usually call Dispose() to avoid this.  (IsDisposed = {2})",
                    GetType().FullName,
                    typeof(SimplifiedDisposableBase).FullName,
                    _isDisposed);

                Debug.WriteLine(errMessages);

                Dispose(false);     // free any unmanaged resources                
            }
#if DEBUG
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errMessages = "Fatal:  Exception occurred within Finalizer ~" + GetType().FullName + "()." + errMessages;
                Debug.WriteLine(errMessages + "  " + ex.Message);

                // Verified that this exception appears in Windows Event Log and includes the originating class message and StackTrace[0]
                throw new Exception(errMessages, ex);
            }
#else
            catch (Exception) 
            {
                /* Don't exit the application */ 
            }
#endif
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add an managed item to be automatically disposed when the class is disposed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposable"></param>
        /// <returns>The argument</returns>
        public T AutoDispose<T>(T disposable) where T : IDisposable
        {
            lock (_autoDisposables)
                _autoDisposables.Add(disposable);

            return disposable;
        }        

        /// <summary>
        /// Derived class can override and chain for support of IDisposable managed resources.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void FreeManagedResources() 
        {
            lock (_autoDisposables)
            {
                _autoDisposables
                    .ForEach(d => d.Dispose());

                _autoDisposables.Clear();
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Derived class can optionally override for support of IDisposable unmanaged resources.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void FreeUnmanagedResources() { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Standard IDisposable Implmentation
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);  // calling multiple times is okay
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436555/calling-suppressfinalize-multiple-times is okay
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)        
        {            
            if (!isDisposing) // if called from finalizer, do not use lock (causes exception)
            {
                if (!_isDisposed)
                {
                    FreeUnmanagedResources();   // always free these                
                    _isDisposed = true;
                }
                return;
            }

            // Remainder is called from IDisposable (not finalizer)

            // Based on "Implemenent IDisposable Correctly" 
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx
       
            lock (_autoDisposables)
            {
                if (_isDisposed)
                    return; // the docs specifically state that Dispose() must be callable multiple times without raising an exception

                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FreeManagedResources();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        FreeUnmanagedResources();   // always free these
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _isDisposed = true;
                }
            }
        }       
    }     
}
```

Comment: `sp_reset_connection` is indeed called every time, same with Linq2Sql. But it does *not* happen if there is an active `TransactionScope`.